# How to find erc20 tokens balance

Tags: ethereum, cryptocurrency, erc20, etherscan

I'm trying to find the balance of ERC20 tokens (such as Tether) of specific addresses.

Actually, I hope to find an API that works like below, get the account address and contract address and return the balance of that specific token.

[Ether Scan token check](https://etherscan.io/tokencheck-tool)

To clarify my purpose, in the TRC20 network, I use [this endpoint](https://developers.tron.network/reference#trc20-transaction-information-by-account-address)
and there is an array of TRC20 token balances in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ethereum there is no built-in API like Trongrid to retrieve the balance of tokens of certain accounts.

If you want to do this, you have to call "balanceOf" method of smart contract tokens.

Infura APIs have an [eth_call method](https://infura.io/docs/ethereum#operation/eth_call) to do this.

Calling this API is a little tricky, I wrote two code snippets for this reason, in JS and Go.

JS: https://gist.github.com/arshamalh/33e6646eb793997f2cc69668bd97010a

Go: https://gist.github.com/arshamalh/9fe035f7fe18cb5387737546ef84bf6c

Answer (score 3):

ERC-20 (and ERC-20-like such as [TRC-20](https://developers.tron.network/docs/trc20), [BEP-20](https://academy.binance.com/en/glossary/bep-20), etc.) token balance of each address is stored **in the contract of the token.**

Trongrid uses a separate DB that aggregates token balances from all `Transfer()` events (defined in the ERC-20 standard) throughout the history of the Tron network. There's possibly a similar third-party service for ERC-20 tokens, but I don't know any. For example Etherscan does have the same info, but they only display it on the address [detail](https://etherscan.io/tokenholdings?a=0x3f5ce5fbfe3e9af3971dd833d26ba9b5c936f0be) page, and they don't provide an API containing this data.

In order to get all ERC-20 token balances of an address, the easiest solution (apart from finding an API that does the same thing as the Trongrid endpoint) is to loop through all token contracts (or just the tokens that you're interested in), and call their `balanceOf(address)` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can call this using one simple Covlanet API call:
[https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#get-/v1/{chain_id}/address/{address}/balances_v2/](https://www.covalenthq.com/docs/api/#get-/v1/%7Bchain_id%7D/address/%7Baddress%7D/balances_v2/)

If you want to switch to any other network, just change the chain_id

Comment: Are there rate limits or required authentification?

Answer (score 1):

Etherscan API supports "Get Address ERC20 Token Holding" call, although this requires PRO subscription.

> https://api.etherscan.io/api    ?module=account
> &action=addresstokenbalance
> &address=0x983e3660c0bE01991785F80f266A84B911ab59b0    &page=1
> &offset=100    &apikey=YourApiKeyToken

As a free workaround, you can get the list of all token transactions for an address and tally them up to get a current list of token balances. Omit contract address. Obviously this process will get lengthy for many transactions.

> https://api.etherscan.io/api    ?module=account    &action=tokentx
> &contractaddress=0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2
> &address=0x4e83362442b8d1bec281594cea3050c8eb01311c    &page=1
> &offset=100    &startblock=0    &endblock=27025780    &sort=asc
> &apikey=YourApiKeyToken

https://docs.etherscan.io/api-endpoints